# What is the correct Content Type of an .xps file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mime-types, content-type

I'm creating an asp.net web application in C# to convert a bunch of `.xps` files to `.pdf` and I want to validate the input file to be converted by its content type instead of the file extension for security reasons.

Comment: From [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-388.htm) it's probably going to be `application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument` or `application/oxps` depending on the file...but the "true" validation will probably be cracking it open (e.g. by using the stuff in the [Xps.Packaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms604618.aspx) namespace) and seeing if a document fails...

Comment: @nkvu I have place both tags into a switch statement but it seems to be an invalid content type for .xps files

Comment: Unsure then (sorry, I'm no expert on the format). The ECMA document linked to in the previous comment does list out a bunch of other content types (starts on pg 398) - perhaps one of those is the one you're looking for?

Answer (score 4):

[According to this resource](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-388.htm) it will be `application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument` or `application/oxps` depending on the file

Comment: just a suggestion: if I repost a comment as an answer I make it community-wiki.

Comment: Firefox just got one from google drive as a ```application/x-zip

Answer (score 0):

According to this [File Signatures Table](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) the signature of XPS files is:

```
50 4B 03 04
```

Comment: You said: _"by its content type instead of the file extension."_ So you read the first bytes of the file which is its signature and compare it with the correct byte sequence. I think this is what you are looking for.